# Debugging Kernel panic

Tags: linux-kernel

After I upsteamed the Kernel from 3.18.19 to 3.18.140. I'm having some issues with the kernel and I'm new at debugging and will like some knowledge on the kernel panics

```
Full crash log :https://del.dog/karnak_kmsg
```

If anyone would like to help me find out it would be appreciated. It's taking me few days to find out the odd issue.

Kernel source : [mt8163_kernel_upstreamed](https://github.com/mt8163/android_kernel_amazon_karnak)

so when I did an objdump on the vmlinux on the kernel it doesn't tell me what file where it has on the kernel. also it seems like the compiler driver has tainted too. 
this is what I get here

```
[  118.822910] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]CPU: 0 PID: 3176 Comm: Compiler driver Tainted: G      D        3.18.140-KFHD8-XTREME #1
[  118.822920] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]Hardware name: MT8163 (DT)
[  118.822929] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][name:traps&]Call trace:
[  118.822944] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][<ffffffc00008adc0>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x15c
[  118.822956] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][<ffffffc00008af30>] show_stack+0x14/0x1c
[  118.822968] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][<ffffffc000abab30>] dump_stack+0x88/0xac
[  118.822980] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][<ffffffc000093e0c>] handle_IPI+0x18c/0x2bc
[  118.822991] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver][<ffffffc000082468>] gic_handle_irq+0x80/0x84
[  118.823001] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]Exception stack(0xffffffc0220d7eb0 to 0xffffffc0220d7fd0)
[  118.823013] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7ea0:                                     00400000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823026] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7ec0: ffffffff ffffffff f71681fe 00000000 f257e5b0 00000000 00000013 00000000
[  118.823039] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7ee0: 00000059 00000000 00000008 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823051] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7f00: 0000000b 00000000 00000004 00000000 f257e5b0 00000000 f1cae0a0 00000000
[  118.823064] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7f20: 00000002 00000000 0000033c 00000000 00000001 00000000 f257e4d0 00000000
[  118.823076] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7f40: 0000000a 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823088] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7f60: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823100] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7f80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823112] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7fa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  118.823123] <0> (0)[3176:Compiler driver]7fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

i also edited the OP with the new longer log instead of short. i wanted this kernel to be fixed as soon as possible, thanks!

Comment: `strnlen()` call with a wrong pointer or absence of NUL terminator on the page size boundary provokes a page fault.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid memory access in the code. Based on dump, you passed invalid pointer and try to do "strlen".

Without knowing entire callpath and what you've changed it is not possible to tell you what is wrong.